# How to make carousel full width on mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How to make my carousel turns to full width when I view on mobile phone or smaller screen device?
Any help would be appreciated.

You can check out the code below or simply view on my codepen here - https://codepen.io/nurzamf-the-lessful/pen/ZEodKGO

```
<div class="contain">
  <div id="owl-carousel" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item">
              <img src="https://blogger.googleusercontent.com/img/a/AVvXsEi9MjLHgzg-8RYlTEZFFZ21FGuldcTSSv2wZHf1nGh6KGgwMAznhwkDlpgyt0pxtMxODbGvftKhgPFbNp46_Jv_45WF64GI7Y5ldi6eZQSTZ5twNS3OkdGY8tBF4vo0Zun3WpLSBiTYy3dBWI0Q0fSyS_mV6PU4XyiW_WA3DcZLSnRKJmiFjG2p6D0_=s1600" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://blogger.googleusercontent.com/img/a/AVvXsEiTZxD__KXQgaGHq_Xm_Jy7kA44vsdwijCR4VrsJI5uGDptJYp2ujRiVX6_6hNA-mCkh9OezjOBddFRYoAVGIT5omKqQcZnn8mFPtyae72oS7I-_pBQs2-5UnYTZ6VVIyBwQQL6RNJrOPjXiiV1jyHBRDOIxi_6Yyw8Nh2hRZfgrYgJiG_F4ljNnJ4J=s1600" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      4
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      5
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.contain {
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
 width:100%;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}
```

```
$('#owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    margin: 0,
    dots: true,
    nav: true,
    items: 2,
})
```

Comment: Can you plz add code snippet to the question so we can understand what you have done and what you want???

Answer (score 0):

Hope It's Work for you !!!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('#owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
                loop: true,
                margin: 0,
                dots: true,
                nav: true,
                items: 2,
                responsiveClass:true,
                responsive:{
                    1000:{
                        items:2,
                        nav:true,
                        loop:true
                    },
                    600:{
                        items:1,
                        nav:true,
                        loop:true
                    },
                    0:{
                        items:1,
                        nav:true,
                        loop:true
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

```css
.contain {
    width: 100%;
}

.item {
     width:100%;
     color: white;
     background-color: salmon;
     display: block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
      
    

    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="contain">
      <div id="owl-carousel" class="owl-carousel">
        <div class="item">
                  <img src="https://blogger.googleusercontent.com/img/a/AVvXsEi9MjLHgzg-8RYlTEZFFZ21FGuldcTSSv2wZHf1nGh6KGgwMAznhwkDlpgyt0pxtMxODbGvftKhgPFbNp46_Jv_45WF64GI7Y5ldi6eZQSTZ5twNS3OkdGY8tBF4vo0Zun3WpLSBiTYy3dBWI0Q0fSyS_mV6PU4XyiW_WA3DcZLSnRKJmiFjG2p6D0_=s1600" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://blogger.googleusercontent.com/img/a/AVvXsEiTZxD__KXQgaGHq_Xm_Jy7kA44vsdwijCR4VrsJI5uGDptJYp2ujRiVX6_6hNA-mCkh9OezjOBddFRYoAVGIT5omKqQcZnn8mFPtyae72oS7I-_pBQs2-5UnYTZ6VVIyBwQQL6RNJrOPjXiiV1jyHBRDOIxi_6Yyw8Nh2hRZfgrYgJiG_F4ljNnJ4J=s1600" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.js"></script>
   
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yo! thank you so much. THis works for me. Really appreciate it